# Stop (long) running SQL query in PostgreSQL when session or requests no longer exist?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm not sure where to start on addressing this issue but if I have a AJAX web application that sends requests to the server and runs long queries on the database (postgresql in my case), is there a way to stop or kill the queries if while still running, the user refreshes the page or closes the session...etc?

Comment: thanks for the answer from Frank. I have found my way in Django by extending the db.backends to handle the problem.

Comment: See also what *not* to do, and why: http://serverfault.com/q/415188/102814

Answer (score 85, accepted):

To stop the query:

```
SELECT pg_cancel_backend(procpid);
```

To kill the database connection:

```
SELECT pg_terminate_backend(procpid);
```

To get an overview of the current transactions, to get the proced id's:

```
SELECT * FROM pg_stat_activity;
```

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-admin.html

Comment: i'm curious if there's any examples showing the use of those function in the web application layer so i can automate this?

Comment: pg_stat_activity shows you the starttime of a query. If you want to kill a transactions when it's too old, just do it. But you have to be a superuser or embed these queries inside a function and use SECURITY DEFINER.

Comment: "procpid" has changed to "pid" as of version 9.2

Comment: This is not the answer for the question "Stop running SQL query WHEN session or requests no longer exist". This is answer for the question "Stop running SQL query MANUALLY FOR ANY REASONS".

Answer (score 4):

Considering your psql configured to run and connect to current dev database this one liner comes handy in development when testing complicated queries which can hung, just kills whatever runs:

If not configured properly - add flags for user/password/database

`psql -c "SELECT procpid FROM pg_stat_activity;" -t | xargs -n1 -I {} psql -c "SELECT pg_cancel_backend({})"`