# How to stop a running query in PostqreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql

First I run this query to see the running queries:

```
select * from pg_stat_activity;
```

then I run this query to stop them:

```
SELECT pg_cancel_backend(pid);
```

but, when I run the pg_stat_activity again, it still shows all the queries!

why it didn't kill the queries?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Stop (long) running SQL query in PostgreSQL when session or requests no longer exist?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3508627/stop-long-running-sql-query-in-postgresql-when-session-or-requests-no-longer-e)

Comment: Did you turn off autocommit? In that case the content from ` pg_stat_activity` will not update unless you end your transaction

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A number of possible explanations:

- You're not looking at an active query, the query text is just the last query that ran on a currently-idle backed. In that case `pg_cancel_backend` will do nothing since there's nothing to cancel. Check the `state` field in `pg_stat_activity`.
- The active query is running in extension code that does not `CHECK_FOR_INTERRUPTS()` during whatever it is doing. This is most typically the case when you're running some extension that does lots of CPU, I/O or network activity using its own libraries, sockets, etc. Particularly things like PL/Perl, PL/Python, etc.
- The active query is running in PostgreSQL back-end code that doesn't check for interrupts in a long running loop or similar. This is a bug; if you find such a case, report it.
- The backend is stuck waiting on a blocking operating system call, commonly disk I/O or a network socket write. It may be unable to respond to a cancel message until that blocking operation ends, but if it receives a `SIGTERM` its signal handler can usually cause it to bail out, but not always.

In general it's safe to use `pg_terminate_backend` as a "bigger hammer". `SIGTERM` as sent by `pg_terminate_backend()` will often, but not always, cause a backend that can't respond to a cancel to exit.

Do *not* `kill -9` (`SIGKILL`) a PostgreSQL backend (`postgres` process). It will cause the whole PostgreSQL server to emergency-restart to protect shared memory safety.

Comment: I regularly stumble upon another pitfall: I usually run with autocommit turneed **off** and `pg_stat_activity` will only update if I end that transaction. It seems the access to `pg_stat_activity` is always done with "repeatable read" isolation level

Answer (score -1):

I should use pg_terminate_backend(pid) instead of pg_cancel_backend(pid).

Comment: If it were that simple we wouldn't bother having `pg_cancel_backend`.